# Wallet_connect Flutter APP Not able to select different wallet

Tags: flutter

I am trying to connect different wallets using the [Wallet_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/wallet_connect) package. However, Every time I click on a different wallet, it opens the same one like all the buttons open Metamask, or all of them open Trust Wallet. I am new to Flutter and to web3 generally

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
import 'package:walletconnect_dart/walletconnect_dart.dart';

class Connect extends StatefulWidget {
  const Connect({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Connect> createState() => _ConnectState();
}

class _ConnectState extends State<Connect> {

  var connector = WalletConnect(
      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
          name: 'IRISA ++',
          description: 'WalletConnect Developer App',
          url: 'https://metamask.io/',
          icons: [
            'https://files.gitbook.com/v0/b/gitbook-legacy-files/o/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
          ]));

  loginUsingMetamask(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!connector.connected) {
      try {
        var session = await connector.createSession(onDisplayUri: (uri) async {
          var _uri = uri;
          await launchUrlString(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        });
        print(session.accounts[0]);
        print(session.chainId);
        setState(() {
          var _session = session;
        });
      } catch (exp) {
        print(exp);
      }
    }
  }
  loginUsingTrust(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!connector.connected) {
      try {
        var session = await connector.createSession(onDisplayUri: (uri) async {
          await launchUrlString(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        });
        setState(() {
        });
      } catch (exp) {
        print(exp);
      }
    }
  }
  loginUsingRain(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!connector.connected) {
      try {
        var session = await connector.createSession(onDisplayUri: (uri) async {
          await launchUrlString(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        });
        setState(() {
        });
      } catch (exp) {
        print(exp);
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, //<-- SEE HERE
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('lib/assets/images/wallet.png', width:400, height:200),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child:Text('Connect your wallet',  style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black)),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            width: 300, // <-- Your width
            height: 100, // <-- Your height
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(// <-- OutlinedButton
              onPressed: () => loginUsingMetamask(context),
              icon:Image.asset('lib/assets/images/metamask.png', width:50, height:50),
              label: const Text('MetaMask',  style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: Colors.white)),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.brown,
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.brown.shade900, width: 3), //<-- SEE HERE

              ),//elevated btton background
            ),
          ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          SizedBox(
              width: 300, // <-- Your width
              height: 100, // <-- Your height
              child: OutlinedButton.icon( // <-- OutlinedButton
                onPressed: () => loginUsingTrust(context),
                icon: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/trustwallet1.png', width:50, height:50),
                label: const Text('Trust Wallet',  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    color: Colors.white)),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade900, width: 3), //<-- SEE HERE
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          SizedBox(
              width: 300, // <-- Your width
              height: 100, // <-- Your height
              child: OutlinedButton.icon( // <-- OutlinedButton
                onPressed: () => loginUsingRain(context),
                icon:Image.asset('lib/assets/images/rainbow.png', width:50, height:50),
                label: const Text('Rainbow',  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                    color: Colors.white)),
                   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue,
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade900, width: 3), //<-- SEE HERE

              ),
              ),
        ),
        ],
    ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any response or different way to do this task

Thank you